# How friendly is checkinstall with CMake rather than autotools?

Tags: debian, cmake, autotools, checkinstall

It's been recommended to me to use the [`checkinstall` mechanism](https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall) to install artifacts I build from source. But - the example involves GNU autotools (`./configure`) while I use CMake. How "friendly" is checkinstall towards CMake builds?

Note: I'm using Devuan 3 Beowulf, in case it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkinstall` doesn’t particularly care about the build framework being used, it cares about the installation process, and those generated by Autotools and CMake are equivalently well-behaved. `checkinstall` with its default settings, or with file system translation, will do the right thing with correctly-written CMake projects.

Comment: "correctly-written" meaning...?

Comment: That’s a vast topic ;-). I’m thinking in particular of `CMakeLists.txt` files which override CMake’s installation functions, or do strange things with the installation prefixes.

Comment: That's still pretty vague, but ok.